# Child processes die when killing parent if one of them is stopped with SIGSTOP

Tags: c, linux, unix

My test code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  int c = fork();
  if (c == 0) while(1);
  c = fork();
  if (c == 0) while(1);
  c = fork();
  if (c == 0) while(1);
  c = fork();
  if (c == 0) while(1);
  while(1);
}
```

So I have one parent and 4 children. When I kill the parent, the children are working fine with init as a parent. But if I stop (with SIGSTOP) one of the children and then kill the parent, the children are killed too. Why this is so?

Comment: Your code is a very nice way to make very hot coffee using your CPU... Especially if you have 4 cores or more...

Comment: Yes, it is :) But this is only for a test and it fulfills this role.

Comment: Great question... fascinated to see the answer. I suspect process groups are involved, but aren't sure how.

Comment: It will make coffee faster if you mix some plain integer computations, floating point, and mmx/sse intrinsics inside your while loops. :-)

Comment: I wonder if somehow this would be in the future xkcd comic with title - coffee machine for dev

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apparently if a process in the process group is stopped, all processes are signalled with SIGHUP and then SIGCONT when the process group leader is terminated. The default handler for SIGHUP terminates the process. It is expected behaviour, as documented in e.g.

http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-10.html

From the above link:

> If termination of a process causes a
>   process group to become orphaned, and
>   some member is stopped, then all are
>   sent first SIGHUP and then SIGCONT.
>
> The idea is that perhaps the parent of
>   the process group leader is a job
>   control shell. (In the same session
>   but a different process group.) As
>   long as this parent is alive, it can
>   handle the stopping and starting of
>   members in the process group. When it
>   dies, there may be nobody to continue
>   stopped processes. Therefore, these
>   stopped processes are sent SIGHUP, so
>   that they die unless they catch or
>   ignore it, and then SIGCONT to
>   continue them.

EDIT:

BTW, strace is a wonderful tool for getting to the bottom of stuff like this. If you attach strace to one of the child processes you will see that SIGHUP is delivered only if one of then is stopped when the parent (i.e. the process group leader) dies.

You need to change the handler for SIGHUP using e.g. sigaction(2) if you want the children processes to survive.

Comment: If you start the program in such a way that it does not use a new process group (e.g. running it with `at` rather than the shell), this behavior is not exhibited.  I sent `STOP` to a child, killed the parent, and the children were still running with this setup.

Comment: By the way, `strace` would have been a nice tool for observing what happens.

Comment: You could also just block `SIGHUP` with `sigprocmask` (or `pthread_sigmask` in a program that may be threaded).

Comment: @Michael E: In that case the process group does not really become orphaned. There is also the little fact that ignored signal dispositions are maintained through execve(), which allows things like nohup to work...

Answer (score 0):

The children belong to the same process group as the parent process and are thus killed together with their parent process.

Hint: don't use `while(1);` to suspend a process. Let it `sleep` indefinitely.

Comment: Apparently not true on my system. Did you even try it ?

Comment: @thkala I've tried it only in Fedora and Archlinux. Can you say, what is yours distr?

Comment: @goreSplatter but then why they aren't killed if I don't send SIGSTOP?

Comment: This sounds dubious. I'm really curious to see the answer to this one since the behavior seen is quite unintuitive.

Comment: About your hint: In my opinion, when examining process interactions, introducing additional signals like sleep's SIGALRM or putting the processes in anything other than a running state adds unnecessary complexity to the analysis.

Comment: @thkala: `while (1) pause();` seems reasonable, though.